# Changing color of input type date on valid input

Tags: javascript, css

So for my regular input type="text" field I use the following code to change the color to green, only after something has been typed in and it is valid:

```
input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown):valid {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Is there any way to the same for an input type="date" field?

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control calender-black" name="dbfield52">
```

The problem seems to be it already is valid since it shows: DD-MM-YYYY as standard value.

Is there a way to do this with css only selectors? Or else maybe with javascript.

Comment: Please do also show how you bind the calendar to the input. I believe you do it in JQuery

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily using [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) css pseudo-class like:

```
input[type="date"]:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

**Demo:**
<sub>*( Just select a value from control and it will add a green border to the date control )*</sub>

```css
/* This is just used to set some styling */
input[type="date"] { padding: .375rem .75rem;font-size: 1rem;line-height: 1.5;border-radius: .25rem;border: 2px solid #ced4da; }
input[type="date"]:focus { outline: 0; }

/* This is the important part */
input[type="date"]:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" class="form-control calender-black" 
     name="dbfield52" required /><br/>
  <p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the input as `required` in order for validation to work:

```css
input[type="date"]:valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control calender-black" name="dbfield52" required>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, the date field shouldn't be required. Is there anyway without making it required with css?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd likely have to use JS instead

Comment: I was afraid of that, will use JS then. Thanks! :)